# Hide extension and variables using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I hide the file's extension and the [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) variables via [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) in one line?

This code doesn't work:

```
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^file-([0-9]+)\.php$ /some_directory/files.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Example:

http://www.example.com/file.php?variable=value

Should be:

http://www.example.com/file

Comment: Please edit your question to give some examples of the URL you input and the result you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a few conditions to the first rule to keep it from looping, you can try changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Then go continue with your second rule, which loks fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better for static pages. You only need to change "index" as your file and change get element according to yours. In example, there is "id" element.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|%20)+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```