# Removing the .php extension from a URL using the .htaccess file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Hide extension and variables using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674705/htaccess-hide-extension-and-variables)

I want to change the my URL.

For example,

from: http://domain-name.com/dir/page1.php
to: http://domain-name.com/dir/?page1

What would be the .htaccess file code for this?

I am not using any CMS. It's just a simple PHP website.

Comment: `/dir/?page1` instead of `/dir/page1`? Why?

Comment: You might want to read this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you want shouldn't be done because `?` is a special character in URLs that stands for "here starts the query string".

For `page.php` to `page` transformation here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Jeffrey, I used ur code but it changed my url as: http://domain-name.com/home/username/public_html/dir/page1 and browser shows 404 error

Comment: i want that ? because it is mentioned in project requirement.

Comment: @ChetanPatil, try the new code.